# How can I give my sister my iPad 2 with the videos and music from my iTunes account intact?

Tags: ipad, itunes-store

I want to give my sister my old iPad without deleting the videos and music I've put on the device. What do I need to do to deactivate it from my iTunes account without deleting the video and music content?

Answer (score 4):

Once she decides to sync the device once, the contents will still be removed. Your sister won't be able to back up the videos and music or sync it to her iCloud, but it should keep playing all the media for months to come. If she erases it or syncs it with a new computer - she can return it to you for a reload or just start fresh with her songs at that point.

To remove your accounts, open the Settings App:

- Remove the passcode (optional but nice to for her to choose one)
- iCloud - tap Delete Account and delete all the content. Optionally delete your backup of this device in Storage & Backup if you don't care to keep that backup around and free up your cloud space.
- Mail, Contacts, Calendars - delete all accounts and data here
- Notes, Reinders, Messages, Facetime - same as above
- Safari - clear cookies and history
- iTunes & App Store - Sign out by tapping the account name for Apple ID
- Music - Sign out of Home Sharing by tapping the Apple ID
- Videos, Game Center - same as above

Sign out of social media - Twitter, Facebook, Flickr, Vimeo

- Privacy - Location Services - Turn Off - that deletes your information from Apple if you chose to share it. Optionally review the apps that have requested access to private data and turn them off / delete the app so she can choose what she shares.
- Privacy - Advertising - Reset Advertising Identifier and optionally Limit Ad Tracking

She should be fine adding her Apple ID and just will want to watch for prompts that indicate if she will ever wipe your videos and music. Depending on what you choose, you might just erase all content and settings and copy the Music and Videos to a $50 hard drive or large USB drive so she can incorporate them in her iTunes library rather than have you surgically remove things. The out of box experience does guide a new user to understand what accounts and settings she can opt in and out of.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the official instructions how to do that.

[iCloud: Change iCloud feature settings](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2613)

and

Removing an associated device or computer from an Apple ID

[To remove a device or computer from your Apple ID:](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4627)

1. Open iTunes.
2. Sign in to your Apple ID by choosing Store > Sign In from the iTunes menu.
3. Choose Store > View My Account from the iTunes menu.
4. From the Account Information screen, click Manage Devices.
5. Click the Remove button next to the device name you would like to unassociate.